# Sending message to AppDelegate not working with in-app purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

I am trying to remove an AdMob banner upon completing an IAP I have setup. The IAP is set up correctly as far as I can tell, the issue I am having for some reason is that when I try to hide the ad after user completes transaction, the ad doesn't hide. The NSLog displays, but the ad doesn't hide. However, I can send the same message from a different method inside my program and it will hide the ad perfectly fine.

Hopefully I can explain it easier with this code:

I am attempting to hide it like this:

When transaction is purchased:

```
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:               
            [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
        break;
```

provideContent method:

```
-(void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifer
{
    if ([productIdentifer isEqualToString:@"product id here"]) {
        AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [app hideBannerApp];
    }
}
```

and now in appdelegate:

```
-(void)hideBannerApp
{
    NSLog(@"Hidden banner");
    [topBanner removeFromSuperview];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:areAdsRemoved forKey:@"areAdsRemoved"];
}
```

For some reason this isn't hiding the ad. the NSLog is displaying in xcode, but ad is not being removed.

BUT, when I call `[app hideBannerApp]` from a different method it works perfectly fine.

Example:

```
-(void)tapButton
{
         if ([productIdentifer isEqualToString:@"product id here"]) {
            AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [app hideBannerApp];
}
```

so if I have a button linked up to this method, it will remove the ad and it works. So why doesn't it work when I do the exact same thing, but with in app purchases?

Comment: The first thing I would do is set a breakpoint and verify that `topBanner` isn't nil

Comment: I set up a breakpoint at `[topBanner removeFromSuperView]`; It's not nil. It printed this description. `<GADBannerView: 0xe102f00; frame = (0 0; 568 32); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xcb676d0>>`

Comment: Is your in-app purchase completing on a background thread?  Try `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [app hiderBannerApp]; });`

Comment: Nope, still getting the same output as before. The NSLog is displaying but the ad isn't being removed. Also using `-(void)tapButton` does not work with this. EDIT: hold on

Comment: Yep still getting the same output, however using `-(void)tapButton` is in fact working. Could it have something to do with iTunes Connect? I didn't submit my IAP for review yet. Probably not, I'm just grasping at straws here.

Comment: No, if the purchase is completing and the method is being invoked then it should work. The most common causes of UI update problems are - nil variables, background threads (we have eliminated these two) and multiple instances of a class/object and operating on the wrong one. The app delegate is a singleton, so that shouldn't be possible. The other possibility I considered was that the add view is being re-added after you remove it, but it is strange it works correctly when you invoke the method from a button

Comment: Hmm, looks like the ad is refreshing when I purchase. I'm using test ads and there are two different types of messages it displays. It shows one message for around 10 seconds and then switches to the next one. When I complete the purchase, the message switches instantly and it looks like the ad is refreshed or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61641/discussion-between-paulw11-and-saleens7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The banner view was being added from the app delegate method `didBecomeActive` - this method may be executed several times during the lifetime of an application resulting in multiple banner views being added, on top of each other.  Only the topmost view was being removed.

The banner add code was moved to `didFinishLaunching`, which resolved the issue